# Solving the following initial and boundary value problem

Tags: boundary-value-problem, heat-equation, initial-value-problems

I’ve been doing some work on the heat equation recently and I’m having problems with the following equation:
$$u_t-\frac{1}{1-t}u_{xx}=0, 0<x<π, t>0$$ with boundary equations:
$$u(x,0)=g(x), 0<x<π$$
$$u_x(0,t)=0=u_x(π,t), t \ge 0$$
I know normally I can use separation of variables to solve this. However, I’m unsure as to how to solve this without knowing $g$. Also, I know the Neumann boundary conditions appear periodic, hence my solution must have $\cos(nx)$ in it. However, in all honesty I’m very stuck with this and have been for the past couple hours. How do I go about solving this boundary initial value problem?

Comment: Well, just use the same method that you know using the function $g$ to be known. Fourier way should work well.